# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 48: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove some lines from a text file with the help of regex, below is the code for same.

```
import re

with open("InteractionsOfTheGreatestLeader.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    pat = re.compile(r"^\d+ ")
    for line in contents:
        if re.search(pat, line):
            continue
    with open("Interactions Of The Greatest Leader.txt",'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
            f.write(line)
```

But I get the following error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d6236d121f23> in <module>
      2 
      3 with open("InteractionsOfTheGreatestLeader.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
----> 4     contents = f.readlines()
      5     pat = re.compile(r"^\d+ ")
      6     for line in contents:

~\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 48: invalid start byte
```

I have tried different encoding like ISO-8859-1, unicode_escape, latin1, etc,. When I use different encodings the new file does not have any text.

`'rb'` does not work.

`errors='ignore'` also results in a empty text file.

What can I do to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give the contents of your text file?

Comment: If this is a one-time change, then surely this would be better accomplished in a text editor.  I presume you know what language the original is written in; that should be a clue to the encoding.

Comment: You should open both files before you start the loop so you can write when you need to.  And one BIG problem you have is that you are changing `f` partway through.

Comment: @TimRoberts the number of lines I want to remove is around 2000 and previously for the same type of file, the above code worked without any problem, I don't understand why is the code not working for this text data.

Comment: @Sujay, I'm sorry, how can I add the contents in this question?

Comment: Have you looked at the file to see what it contains at character 48?  And if you only have one pattern, it's one vi command: `:g/^\d+ /d`.

Comment: The book contains quotes in Arabic.  Does your text have Arabic characters?  Have you tried character set "Windows-1256" or "cp1256"?

Comment: @TimRoberts The book's text does not contain any Arabic characters I removed them earlier but I did not try the above encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't know the language, you can treat both files as binary files.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(br"^\d+ ")
with open("InteractionsOfTheGreatestLeader.txt", "rb") as fin:
    with open("Interactions Of The Greatest Leader.txt","wb") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if not re.search(pat, line):
                fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much:)
The above method worked.